# C - Struct Constructor and Deconstructor

Tags: c, pointers

If I have a struct like:

```
struct Cell
{
    unsigned int *x, *y;
    char flag;
};
```

Would the following constructor and deconstructors be sufficient for safely allocating and de-allocating memory?

```
// Constructor function.
struct Cell *Cell_new()
{
    struct Cell *born = malloc(sizeof(struct Cell));
    if (born == NULL)
        return NULL;
    born->x = NULL;
    born->y = NULL;
    born->flag = false;
    return born;
}

// Deconstructor function.
// When called, use Cell_destroy(&cell);
char Cell_destroy(struct Cell **cell)
{
    free(cell);
    cell = NULL;
}
```

Is this correct?

One thing I don't understand is if I do:

```
struct Cell *myCell = Cell_new();
Cell_destroy(&myCell);
```

When I'm calling `destroy`, it is expecting an address to a pointer (a pointer to a pointer) and yet I'm providing an address to a struct.

What I mean is

My function expects:

`Pointer -> Pointer -> Tangible Object`

What I'm giving it:

`Pointer -> Tangible Object`

Is this flawed logic? I've been looking up this for awhile so it's safe to say I might be confusing myself.

Comment: all of your "constructor"'s body could be simplified to `ìf (born != NULL) memset (born, 0, sizeof(struct Cell));`

Comment: @AlterMann if I change `false` with `FALSE` I get a `identifer "FALSE" is undefined` compile error. I thought in C you had to define or enumerate booleans or just use `0` and `1`?

Comment: @Hatefiend, chux, sorry, brainstorm, bools in C are used in small letters

Comment: @tofro: Not portably. There is no guarantee that all-bits-zero is a representation of a null pointer value (though it very commonly is).

Comment: @tofro `0` is the same as `0x0000000` right? It's safe to use as `NULL` and `false`?

Comment: @Hatefiend: `0` is a null pointer constant; that's purely a compile-time entity. The runtime representation of a null pointer is unspecified.

Comment: @AlterMann You might be getting confused with C++? Neither `FALSE` or `false` will work without imports. [Just tried](http://i.imgur.com/SLBcW8R.png)

Comment: `&myCell`, the value you're passing to `Cell_destroy()`, **is** a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: Starting with C99, `bool`, `false`, and `true` are defined in `<stdbool.h>`.

Comment: Odd, my program crashes if I attempt to include `<stdbool.h>`

Comment: @Hatefiend, too much time time using gtk this week :)

Comment: @Keith Thompson Is an all-bits-zero for a `void *` a null pointer?

Comment: @chux: Probably for most implementations, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @Hatefiend: What do you mean by "my program crashes". Are you saying that adding `#include <stdbool.h>` causes your program to crash *at run time*? That would be very surprising.

Comment: @Hatefiend Setting a pointer to `NULL` after freeing what it points to is an anti-pattern, and this should only be done if there's some specific reason to do it.

Comment: @David Schwartz disagree with "Setting a pointer to `NULL` after freeing what it points to is an anti-pattern".  OP's code is passing in the address of structure and _should_ update `free (*cell); *cell = NULL;`  (free the fields first would normally also be expected)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If I don't de-reference the pointer that I pass into `destroy` then isn't it possible for me to use the now-unallocated memory that is the result of `free`? Surely that is bad and setting the pointer to `NULL` solves that?

Comment: On practically all real-life implementations of C, `memset`on a struct sets pointers to NULL and bools to false. Everything else is nitpickery.

Comment: @Hatefiend It's possible whether or not you set the pointer to `NULL`, because there can be any number of other pointers that point to the same space or into some part of the allocated space other than its beginning. Just don't mess with a pointer unless you know it points to something valid. Occasionally, it might make sense to set a pointer to `NULL` as the way to know that that pointer doesn't point to something valid. But that's an occasional use case specific decision, not a generic rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct to pass a parameter of type `struct Cell **` to the destructor function because, this function will change the value of the pointer intended.

So, if you want to free the object and set the pointer to NULL, you can write:

```
void Cell_destroy(struct Cell **cell)
{
    free(*cell);
    *cell = NULL;
}
```

Note how `cell` is de-referenced.

Comment: What does the function return?  Perhaps make it `void`.

Comment: Well, you have to ask the OP. Ofcourse the function must return a value if its return type is not void.

Comment: Oh woops yes I meant to put a return value in but my head got stuck around the whole free thing. I was thinking return false if something went wrong with freeing up allocated memory but I suppose that's impossible?

Comment: @Hatefiend If `*cell` was NULL, you can return a value to indicate something went wrong. But make the return type `int`.

Comment: Why use `int` since that is `4` bytes as apposed to `char`'s 1 byte to represent `1` and `0`?

Comment: @Hatefiend `int` is normally more common than `char`. You can use `char` but, it's not like your'e running out of memory for a difference of 3 bytes :)

Comment: #AllBytesMatter  :D

Comment: @Hatefiend Using `char` vs `int` can easily not increase data memory usage as code is likely optimized for `int` usage.  OTOH, using a return type of `char` may _increase_ program memory.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider the memory pointed to by the `x` and `y` pointers in the struct. If those pointers are non-null, what part of the code is responsible ("owns") that memory? A typical thing to do would be to check for null in `Cell_destroy` and if x or y is non-null, call `free` on them as well if it is the case that some other part of your Cell ADT (abstract data type) is allocating that memory dynamically via `malloc`. To be sure, `free(cell)` will only free memory used by the struct itself, not any memory pointed to by `x` and `y`.

Regarding `Cell_destroy` taking a pointer-to-a-pointer so it can set the passed-in pointer to null, that is an atypical way for a destructor function to work ... the way `free` itself works is more typical - nulling out the passed-in pointer is typically a job left for the caller of `free`.

Comment: If I cell `free(cell)`, does it go through every pointer inside my `struct Cell` and free up those as well?

Comment: @Hatefiend No. That would be a disaster -- what if you still need those objects?

Comment: Oh ok gotcha. Do I need to `free` `x`x and `y` even though I will never call `malloc` on them? Since they are just integers surely I can use them by saying `x = 1` without doing `x = malloc(sizeof(int)`?

Comment: As you've defined them they are not integers, they are pointers to integers. If x and y should be integers, drop the * in the struct definition and you would not need to call 'free' on them.

Comment: @thewmo Yes they were originally integers but I have the need to set them to NULL to warn my program that the coordinates currently mean nothing. What I am a bit confused about though is if the coordinates (which represent the location in my 2d array) **ARE** actually zero, then would `(x == NULL)` be `true`? If so what `unsigned` value could I use indicating that the coordinates are currently not set?

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. There are issues of type safety here, treating a pointer as an integer. Typically NULL would be equivalent to 0 if cast to an integer type, yes. (x == NULL would be true if x == 0, assuming you added the casts to satisfy the type system).

Comment: Your options - if you need the full unsigned range, then your best bet is probably a separate boolean flag field indicating if the value is used. If you can use a signed field but the value is never legitimately negative, -1 is a common value used as a flag meaning "invalid".

Comment: Or create a `struct` that holds an integer and a bool and use that consistently to handle "an optional integer".

Answer (score 1):

Codes needs to free the same pointer it allocated.  Free the de-referenced value.

Code is also missing a return value.  Suggest simply using a `void` function.

Code should also free the field's pointers `x` and `y`.

Code should be tolerant of repeated calls with same pointer and a null pointer. Add `if (*cell)`

```
void Cell_destroy(struct Cell **cell) {
  if (*cell) {
    free((*cell)->x);
    free((*cell)->y);
    free(*cell);
    *cell = NULL;
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you free `x` and `y`? OP sets them to NULL.Perhaps you should add an `if` statement before calling free on those pointers as well?

Comment: @machine_1 `free(NULL)` is OK.  No need for a test to see if there are `NULL`.  Certainly OP's code is minimally and does not show the things that may happen to `x` and `y`.  Certainly if `x,y` are not free by the time of the destructor, there should be free'd.

Comment: @4386427 Consider OP's code `struct Cell *myCell = Cell_new();
Cell_destroy(&myCell);`  `Cell_new()` may return `NULL`.  `Cell_destroy(&myCell);` should cope with that.  `free(myCell)` would.

Comment: Well, if you call free for x and y, you must check for NULL - true. Still we don't know whether those calls should be made. Anyway, I just disagree to the concept of passing a double pointer and setting the freed pointer to NULL. But +1 for bringing free of x and y up.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct.

The destroy function should not return char. It should have return type void.

Further the function should take a pointer instead of a double pointer and you should not set cell to null. And do not take address of myCell when calling destroy.

Comment: I thought returning `char` indicating if `free` succeeded was smart to do but I suppose it's not needed. If I don't pass in a double pointer to `destroy` then my `cell` pointer that I pass into `destroy` will not be `NULL`. Doesn't this mean that it'd be possible for me to call `cell` and enter non-allocated memory? From what I read people say pass in `**` to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Just like free does not change the pointer provided, your destroy shouldn't either. It migth be an unnecessary performance penalty.

Comment: BTW free will be a succes or a real bad failure that you can not handle with a return value.

Comment: @Hatefiend It's always possible for you to do bone-headed things. That's not a justification for *intentionally* doing bone-headed things. Setting the caller's pointer to NULL is bone-headed. The caller can NULL the pointer if they want its value changed, and if they don't, well, [this](http://pastebin.com/QpzPMg7P) happens.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I see your logic but then again I've never ever called `free` on a pointer in which I had plans to use again.

Comment: @Hatefiend Then your setting the pointer to `NULL` created risk and gained you nothing, that's typical of anti-patterns.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If you did `int x[10]` and then called `x[15] = 5`, you would consider that to be a horrific error because you are using unallocated memory and could possibly spur a segment fault. By letting a freed pointer be NULL you are enabling that to possibly occur. If you don't dereference the pointer, a developer could forget and accidentally keep using the pointer and be relying on volatile memory.

Comment: @Hatefiend But even if you do set it to `NULL`,  a programmer could make that same mistake. For example, they might keep a copy of the pointer or they might have a pointer to an object inside the object you freed. By setting pointers to `NULL` (in cases other where you have an good reason for doing so), you encourage sloppy programming on the assumption that a pointer that doesn't point to a valid object will always be `NULL`, and there are many, *many* situations where this is not the case. It's a bad practice. Don't do it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Gotta apologize to you. I was ignorant and I thought I would never run into a situation where what you said would be a problem. Today I was working with [deconstructors in threads](http://i.imgur.com/WyMqAVq.png) and sure enough they were de-referencing my pointers right before I planned to re-use them. The pointers are instance variables so it's not like I can discard them after I'm done with them. I think that's basically what I hadn't though about when I was posting yesterday. Anyways, this is a big message saying you were right and I learned my lesson haha.

Comment: @Hatefiend Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be possible to teach people to avoid mistakes just by telling them that something is a mistake and that bad things will happen. It is a programming maxim that you have to make every mistake at least once, period. On the bright side, this means that the more mistakes you made, the more progress you are making to becoming better.